# In how many ways can a kindergarten teacher distribute five indistinguishable books to $20$ children?

Tags: combinatorics

A kindergarten teacher has five books to distribute to 20 children in her class. How many ways are there for her to distribute the books if they are all the same and there is no restriction on the number of books that can be given to any child?

Comment: Without the word "probability" appearing in the question, this does not qualify as a probability problem.  This is a *counting* problem from combinatorics which although is a common tool to analyze and approach certain probability problems does not by itself make a problem a probability problem.

Comment: The problem type here is a textbook example of a balls-in-bins problem (books=balls, and children=bins).  The standard solution works here as well.  See [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a multiset problem. The formula for this is $\binom{n + k -1}{k - 1}$ where n is indistinguishable balls and k is distinguishable bins. You have five books and 20 children so: $$ \binom{5 + 20 -1}{20 - 1} = \binom{24}{19} = 42504$$

Comment: To the OP (i.e. original poster): re the answer, see also [this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).